# Finding a basis for the nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 5 & 3 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & -4 & 2\\ 6 & -14 & -13 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}

I need to find the null space for this matrix. After performing row operations $R_3 + 3R_1$, then $R_{new row 3}$ + $R_2$, I got the reduced row echelon form. (the variable I chose were $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$). I identified the pivot variables as $x$ and $y$, after expressing both of these in terms of the free variables $z$ and $w$, I got $$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w\\
\end{bmatrix} = z \begin{bmatrix}
23/2\\
4\\
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix} + w\begin{bmatrix}
-11/2\\
-2\\
0\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$, and then chose both the column vectors alongside $z$ and $w$ as the basis for the nullspace. However the answer given is $$\begin{bmatrix}
23\\
8\\
2\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
9\\
4\\
0\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your reduced row echelon form? Two row operations don't sound like enough to get to a _reduced_ form for a matrix with that many nonzero entries.

Comment: The rank of the matrix is $3$, so the null-space has dimension $1$. The first vector you mentioned is member of the null-space.

Comment: If you multiply $A$ with the second vector, you see that it does not belong to the null-space.

Comment: The given answer is also incorrect.

Comment: Are all the signs of the last column of your matrix right? If the column was $[-1,-2,1,0]$ instead, the matrix would have rank 2, _and_ $[9,4,0,2]$ would be in the null space.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I just checked. Element four of row 2 should be $-2$ instead of $2$.

Comment: In this case, the given answer is correct. Well spot it, Henning!

Comment: After the correction, both of my basis vectors are half of those given in the answer. Since basis are not unique, mine are also correct right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 5 & 3 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & -4 & 2\\ 6 & -14 & -13 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Row reduced form of matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -\frac{23}{2} & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -4 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}
$$
So basis is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}23 \\ 8 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

If matrix is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 5 & 3 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & -4 & -2\\ 6 & -14 & -13 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Row reduced form of matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -\frac{23}{2} & -\frac{9}{2}\\ 0 & 1 & -4 & -2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}
$$
So basis is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}23 \\ 8 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}9 \\ 4 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: the last two basis vectors you wrote (for -2), is any scalar multiple of both of these also basis?

Comment: Basis are independent vectors in any subspace and if you consider any scalar multiple of both these basis then that would be dependent on these vectors so they would not be called the basis.

Comment: No I don't think you understand my question. I'm saying if we have $v_1$, $v_2$ as basis for a subspace, then is $kV_1$,$bV_2$ also a basis for that subspace? (b and k are scalars)

Comment: A set of vectors in a vector space V is called a basis, or a set of basis vectors, if the vectors are linearly independent and every other vector in the vector space is linearly dependent on these vectors . If you multiply that vector with any scalar , say $kv_1=kv_1+0v_2$ so it is dependent on $v_1$ and $v_2$ therefore $kv_1$ cannot be a basis. Similarly $kv_2$.

Comment: I think you're wrong.

Comment: (1,0) and (0,1) are basis in $R^2$ then according to your statement (5,0) should also be a basis which is not since it is dependent on (1,0) and (0,1). .

Comment: No that's not even my argument. I'm saying if (1,0),(0,1) is a basis, then (5,0),(0, 3) can also be basis. Or to generalize, (k,0),(0,b), where k and b are scalars, can also be basis.

Comment: You can say that because we can ignore the scalars .